# Possible data loss on TcpClient?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, barcode, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm writing some code for a production line. In particular I need to integrate some barcode reader into the line.

For many (wrong) reason I had to end up like you are about to see.
Also, I was new to that field at the time I wrote that.

The issue: Sometimes, the reader reads the code (and send the image via ftp) but I get no data in my software and I need to understand why.

This is how initialize my reader (I have multiple reader, each with different IP but same port)

```
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, scannerPort);
server.Start();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    log.Debug("Waiting for scanner connection");
    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, server);
});
thread.Start();
```

and this is my main method:

```
try
{
    object _lockObj = new object();
    using (TcpClient client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(res))
    {
        int i; 
        server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAsyncConnection, server);
        string address = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        string senderIp = address.Split(':')[0];

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[2048];

        while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
        {
            log.Debug("Start");
            lock (_lockObj)
            {
                log.Debug("Lock");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
                string rawCode = string.Empty;
                bool isCrFound = false;

                foreach (byte c in bytes.Where(x => x != 0))
                {
                    if (c != (char)13 && !isCrFound)
                    {
                        if (c == (char)29)
                        {
                            sb.Append("<GS>");
                        }
                        else
                            sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(c));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isCrFound = true;
                    }
                }
                rawCode = sb.ToString();
                log.Debug("Raw code from {0} -> {1}", senderIp, rawCode);
                if (rawCode.StartsWith("ERROR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    log.Debug("Operator - Errore reading code {0} from {1}", rawCode, senderIp);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Process code
                }
                log.Debug("End");
            }
            log.Debug("Unlock");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("Error on the async connect operation: {0}, Stack: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
}
```

So basically everytime a sensor trigger, data is sent to my socket.
This works pretty well until the line starts to speed up (like 3/4 code/second); that is when data loss happen.

Now, I don't know where the issue is. Could be the devide, my implementation, resources management (byte array was 1024, I still have to try the 2048)
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

- I already stripped some log for brevity
- I need a lock because when a sensor triggers too close to another, messages got overlapped (to that add different business reason)
- When I loose Codes, I don't have anything in my log; the log, usually looks like:

  - start
  - Lock
  - lot of stuff
  - end
  - unlock

Lost codes don't leave any trace on my log... so I don't think it's something related to data discarded.

What I'd like to know if there is a way to do this kind of thing better in a context like mine.

Comment: add more debugging to it, for both the end point and this.

Comment: I've not read your code but don't forget that you aren't guaranteed that two separate messages sent arrive as two separate messages. At this level, it isn't packet based, it's a stream of bytes.

Comment: TCP isn't *messages*, it's streams of bytes. If you want messages, it's up to *you* to implement those atop TCP or move to a higher level protocol that implements them for you. You need to pay attention to the return value from `Read` - it tells you how many bytes have been placed in your buffer. You can't just assume the whole contents of your buffer are valid and related to your most recent `Read` call.

Comment: As long as your TcpClient is connected, the underlying protocol ensures that **all** data arrives and in the right order. Other than the `0`s you dispose (on purpose I assume) I can see nothing that would reasonably result in data loss and to be honest *"like 3/4 code/second"* doesn't sound like a lot of data. Do you have a particular reason for the `lock`? Also, others have mentioned it already but I wanted to point this out specifically: TCP is a stream of data, not discreet packets (not on your end at least). You can **never** ensure that all your data arrives at once or only one packet.

Comment: As above said, it's a stream of bytes, it could be that you have reached the crc char (13) and then you just ignore the rest of the stream. It could be that the "loss data" is there but you ignore it.

Comment: To add to what I already said, it's not guaranteed that one message will arrive in one "Read()", either.

Comment: as @OfirWinegarten mentiones, you might be simply ignoring your data. it is possible that when stream gets more hit you'll read 2 messages that were send separate on the other end into one array. due to isCrFound = true line you will ignore the whole second message i belive. you need to process data differently on the receiver side considering both: 1. sticking 2 separate parts of one message from 2 reads 2. getting 2 messages in one array and reading both

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys...to answer all: I already got rid of the redundant log to keep it short. I get rid of zeroes cause every sensor filled the array with zeros in the end. I need a lock because when 2 code are received too close, the get on different thread and i had overlapping decoded codes, oh and the real problem is that when i loose codes, I don't have the "Start" and "Lock" debug lines...either data doesn't arrive, or something happen before the "start"

Comment: @Tom you are losing data because after `isCrFound` becomes true - you ignore the rest of data arrived. Bytes can arrive in whatever configuration, including multiple "messages" together (though there is no such thing as message in TCP). So when multiple codes arrive together - you read first one and throw away the rest.

Comment: BTW, locking on a local variable seems useless.

Comment: Lost codes don't leave any trace on my log... so I don't think it's something related to data discarded.

of course it is/might be: if in one read you get 2 messages you will get no info in your logs as you are still between lock and end log entries, you seem still not to understand that its not a series of messages you are getting as they were send. you receive a stream and some of messages you might get in 2 or more pieces, but you might read 2 or more messages at one time as well